# Relational table to Dynamodb

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, relational-database

I worked with relational databases for a long time, and now I am going to work with DynamoDB. After, working with relational databases, I am struggling to design some of our current SQL tables in DynamoDB. Especially, deciding about partition and sort keys. I will try to explain with an example:

Current Tables:

```
Student: StudentId(PK), Email, First name, Last name, Password, SchoolId(FK)
School: SchoolId(PK), Name, Description
```

I was thinking to merge these tables in DynamoDB and use SchoolId as the Partition Key, StudentId as the sort key. However, I saw some similar examples use StudentId as the Partition Key.

And then I realized, we use "username" in each login functionality, so the application will query with "username"(sometimes with a password, or auth token) a lot. This situation makes me think about; SchoolId as the Partition Key and Username as the sort key.

I need some ideas about what would be the best practice in that case and some suggestions to give me a better understanding of NoSQL and DynamoDb concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NoSql you should try to list down all your use cases first and then try to model the table schema.

Below are the use-cases that I see in your application

1. Get user info for one user with userId (password, age, name,...)
2. Get School info for user with userId (className, schoolName)
3. Get All the student in one school.
4. Get All the student in one class of one school.

Based on these given access pattern this is how I would have designed the schema

```
|    pk     |     sk        |   GSI1 PK          |  GSI1 SK            |  
|  12345    |    metadata   |                    |                     | Age:13 | Last name: Singh | Name:Rohan | ...
|  12345    |    schoolMeta |  SchoolName: DPS   | DPS#class5          | className:5 |
```

With the above schema you can solve the identified use cases as

1. Get user info for one user with userId

   `Select * where pk=userId and sk=metadata`
2. Get school info for user with userId

   `Select * where pk=userId and sk=schoolMeta`
3. Get All the student in one school.

   `Select * where pk=SchoolId from table=GSI1`
4. Get All the student in one class.

   `Select * where pk=SchoolId and sk startswith SchoolId#className from table=GSI1`

**But the given schema suffers from the drawback that**

1. If you want to change school name you will have to update too many rows.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, this is very helpful. I have just two more questions; for the first use case: "Get user info for one user with userId (password, age, name,...) ", the application will get user info with "username" instead of userID. In that case do you think I need to use "username" as the partition key? And my second question is about the sort key, what do you refer by saying "metadata" in my case. Thanks again for the detailed answer.

Comment: pk should be the key you think you will try to do a fetch against. There is no constraint on that, the only catch there is that it should be random enough so that hot partition does not occur. `metadata` is just a key you could use any other constant name as well, the only thing to note is, this name can not be changed later and application should be aware of this name to do a fetch